# Drupal Webform email receipt

Tags: email, drupal, drupal-webform

I'm trying to set up an email receipt to send to the user who fills out the form.
I'm using Webform 6.x-3.1. On this help page for Webform "admin/help/webform" it hints at that function by stating this **"Once finished adding fields, you may want to send e-mails to administrators or *back to the user who filled out the form*. Click on the Emails sub-tab underneath the Webform tab on the piece of content."**
It looks like they took out the "Additional processing" ability with this version.

I tried adding an hidden email field under the "E-mails" tab to send an email to the form submitter but didn't work. What I di  was add a hidden field called "email_user" and for the default value, gave it %post[email]   because the email field they fill out is "email". It doesn't look like it's grabbing the post.

Does anyone have this working or understand how to get it done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might be misunderstanding the E-mails subtab. For an example, start fresh with a new Webform node and try this:

1. In the "Form components" subtab, add three components: "Example First Name" (type: textfield), "Example Last Name" (type: textfield), and "Example Email Address" (type: email). For this example, mark them all as "Mandatory" (although I don't think that setting is required for confirmation emails).
2. Check out the "E-mails" subtab. See how the "Component value:" dropdown now displays "**Example Email Address**" as an option? Leave that selected, and click on the "Add" button to the right.
3. On the next page, you can define the email header and body, as I'm sure you've seen before. Note at the top, however, the **E-mail to address:** field, which still has your "Example Email Address" component selected. This means that the confirmation email will be sent to the email address that is entered in the Example Email Address form field upon submission.
4. Now click the "View" tab and try out your form: Enter an example name and a real email address, submit, and check to see if you receive the Webform-generated confirmation email.

In short: you don't use the E-mails subtab to define additional fields/components for your form; you use it to select which *existing* form field(s) should be the recipient of a confirmation email.

Comment: Yikes!! I forgot to make my email field component a type of "email". I had it set to text field, that's why it wasn't showing up in the dropdown list. All good now.   
Thanks Peter.